# Is this cypher neo4j query working as I expect?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have a graph with Users and Places. Users are r:MEMBER_OF Places. I want to find suggestions of Places that a User might like to be a MEMBER_OF based on what Users are in which Places. So if a User is already in 1 Place, and many other users that are in that 1 Place are also in another Place, then that Place should be suggested, as long as the original User is not already in that Place.

So here's what I've come up with, and it does yield results, but I want to make sure that the suggested Places are not just random. Is this query properly ranking Places that should be suggested? Or is it just a random collection of Places that fit the criterion?

```
MATCH (a:User {username:'johndoe123'})-[:MEMBER_OF]->()<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(b:User)
MATCH (b)-[r:MEMBER_OF]->(suggestion)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(suggestion)
RETURN suggestion limit 5
```

Comment: I suggest you create test cases and run your query against actual data. Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but you are return a suggestion every time another user is associated with that Place. You probably only want to return each  Place suggestion once, and you probably want to rank the suggestions by their frequency. Try this.

```
MATCH (a:User {username:'johndoe123'})-[:MEMBER_OF]->()<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(b:User)
MATCH (b)-[r:MEMBER_OF]->(suggestion)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(suggestion)
RETURN suggestion, count(*) AS otherUserCount
ORDER BY otherUserCount DESC limit 5
```